# How to access and edit list of blocked callers

Tags: windows-10-mobile, call-sms-filter

On Windows Mobile 10, I blocked a caller. Everytime he calls, I get a notification that allows me to unblock him if I wanted. So far so good.

But I have also temporarily blocked people and I can't find the list of blocked callers to review, edit and unblock. But how do I unblock a caller without this notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option to unblock is a bit buried, but...

If you go into `Phone` and use the `...` button in the toolbar at the bottom of the screen, one of the options there is "Blocked calls". Going in to that lists every call that has been blocked historically. Tapping an entry for the number you want to unblock will give details, and in the `...` menu on *that* screen, there is the option to "Unblock number"